# What parts of speech is "Like" in this Sentence

Tags: parts-of-speech

This is a line from Ruskin Bond's short story, "Eyes Have It."
—"What is it like outside?"I asked.

I am more inclined to call 'like' an adverb in this sentence but cannot figure out what should be its literal meaning. But at the very next moment discard the idea of branding it as adverb as it is used with a linking verb which always presupposes a complement in the form of adjective or noun. Any help?

Comment: No; it's an adjective by virtue of being predicative complement of "be". It's one of just a handful of transitive adjectives, hence the obligatory NP complement "what".

Comment: Shouldn't it be context-dependent in this case as to what POS _like_ belongs. I might answer that as:It's _like_ 50 degrees on the outside, in which case _like_ is an adjective modifying _50 degrees._ On the other hand, if I say _it's like sunny on the outside_, _like_ would be an adverb with the meaning _probably, nearly, approximately, etc._, depending on the situation.

Comment: @user405662 Yes, but in the OP's example it's clearly an adjective.

Comment: @405662 In 'It's like 50 degrees on the outside', 'like' is arguably (and I'd say) a parenthetical with little matrix-sentence-related semantic force, in fact a pragmatic marker acting either as an intensifier (italicisation would have a similar effect) or an affectation of speech (man).  but 'Shouldn't it be context-dependent in this case' is unnecessary; POS is always dependent on actual usage. OP's _like_ is not the one you introduce.